# How to add SSL (TLS) for outgoing SMTP server in virtualmin?

Tags: ssl, smtp, mail-server, virtualmin

I have setup centos7 server with virtualmin installed. I am using postfix as MTA but it shows that my outgoing (smtp) server is not encrypted. How to encrypt my outgoing smtp server running on port 587?

hostname: host.crystalsoft.com.np